# How to remove extension name from multiple files in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket, gsutil

I have files like
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/12321.jpg
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/44666.jpg
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/89774.jpg
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/63333.jpg
...

in google cloud storage and I want the end result as
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/12321
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/44666
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/89774
gs://bucketname/thumbnails/63333
...

I couldn't find an appropriate gsutil command for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gsutil doesn't have built-in support to do what you're trying to do. You could generate a script to do it using something like:

```
gsutil ls gs://your-bucket/**.jpg | sed 's/\(.*\).jpg/gsutil mv & \1/'
```