# How to remove .jpg from file name with gsutil over 20000 files already in bucket

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage, bucket, gsutil

I have about 30000 images in bucket which many of have .jpg extension. How can I remove .jpg with gsutil from filenames?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828966/how-to-remove-extension-name-from-multiple-files-in-google-cloud-storage/49831747#49831747

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extension name from multiple files in google cloud storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828966/how-to-remove-extension-name-from-multiple-files-in-google-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments, this appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828966/how-to-remove-extension-name-from-multiple-files-in-google-cloud-storage/49831747#49831747).

As the accepted answer in the above question mentions, try something like:

```
gsutil ls gs://your-bucket/**.jpg | sed 's/\(.*\).jpg/gsutil mv & \1/'
```

Note that this may not work as expected if you've configured your preferred API to be XML in your `.boto` config file, since the XML API returns only the first 1,000 results for `ls`.